# Select elements in order

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Let's say I have this XML snippet as input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>This is A</a>
    <b>This is B</b>
    <c>This is C</c>
</root>
```

How can write an XSL stylesheet so that I can reorder the elements as `b`, `c` and then `a`? Sorting is not possible as the elements in my actual problem have no discernible patterns.

I tried the following but the output is in document order, i.e. `a`, `b`, `c`.

```xml
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="b | c | a">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a better way than reconstructing them one-by-one?

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="b" /></b>
        <c><xsl:value-of select="c" /></c>
        <a><xsl:value-of select="a" /></a>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorting *is* possible:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="sort-order">|b|c|a|</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="a|b|c">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, concat('|', name(), '|')))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Clever hack. I will try to weave this into my problem.